# ¿Cómo referenciar un dato en un formulario para que me tome el valor?

Tags: php, laravel, formularios

Tengo un sistema de inventario el cual tiene una sistema de pedidos, para que un empleado pueda requerir equis producto.

Los datos sí me los toma el formulario:
[image: imagen de datos]

Pero no sé cómo referenciar el dato 'quantity' para que este se guarde

Este es mi `CartController`

```
 public function add(Request $request){
   
    $producto = Producto::find($request->id);

    $userId = auth()->user()->id; // or any string represents user identifier
    Cart::add(
        $producto->id, 
        $producto->descripcion, 
        "quantity"->quantity
       
    );
    return back();

}
```

El error que me da es: `Attempt to read property "quantity" on string`

Comment: Buen día, no entiendo muy bien tu pregunta, ¿Deseas obtener `quantity` de la petición que viene desde el formulario? ¿No es suficiente con `$request->quantity`? ¿Haz hecho `dd()` de `$request` y de `$producto` para ver si lo que tienen es lo que deseas utilizar? ¿Qué sucede si la cantidad solicitada es mayor a la cantidad disponible en `Producto`?

Comment: sí, lo logré dos segundos después de publicar la pregunta.  No he hecho lo del dd(), voy a investigar eso porque primera vez que lo veo. Y con lo de qué sucede, estoy viendo cómo hacer para que no te deje agregarlo si la cantidad supera el stock disponible, ¿podría ayudarme con eso?

Comment: Que bueno que encontraste la respuesta!. Antes de solicitar ayuda sería bueno que intentaras algo, si te salen errores entonces crea una nueva pregunta. Saludos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En laravel, normalmente el patron ofrece la facilidad de las escala de codigo; esto quiere decir que tus estructuras de datos, clases, entidades, etc llevan un patron estandar...

particularmente laravel implementan setter y getter: esto quiere decir que todos los objetos y Clases llevaran propiedades privadas y los getter/setter para acceder a ellos..

cuando intentas hacer esto:

```
$object->pripiedad;
```

te dara error, en laravel se espera que intentes algo como:

```
$object->getPripiedad();
```

nativamente laravel implementa `->get()` para sus entidades e incluso tambien esta para bases de datos:

- Para find(n), recupera una fila basada en la clave principal que es 'n'.
- Para first(), recupera la primera fila entre todas las filas que se ajustan a las cláusulas where.

Esto tambien aplica para los request, esto nace de la implementacion de OOP (POO Programacion Orientada a Objetos)

Answer (score 1):

ya pude, bastaba con

```
$request->get('quantity')
```

Comment: por que bastaba con eso???

Comment: por como lo entiendo, el `$request->get('dato equis aquí')` lo que hace es traerte el valor que tiene el input del formulario de ese dato; como yo lo estaba haciendo antes, o sea `"quantity"->quantity` no me traía ningún dato

Comment: por que no te traia el dato???

Comment: tengo la impresion que estas aprendiendo laravel sin saber php XD.

Comment: `"quantity"` es una cadena y no puede tener propiedades como si se tratara de un objeto, es por eso que se solucionó con el método de Laravel para obtener variables proporcionadas por URL desde el objeto `$request`.

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 php lo vi en la universidad, pero genuinamente estoy aprendiendo como que todo a la vez de nuevo, probablemente malo de mi parte, pero ahí voy struggling KJDSHFKJD

Comment: @KarelixAlejandra eso quiere decir que hay cosas que refrescar, Lectura  Obligatoria: https://phptherightway.com/